# Creating a Min heap or a Max heap

Tags: algorithm, time, heap, complexity-theory, time-complexity

> For creating a Min heap or a Max Heap of n elements, time taken would be O(nlogn) for creating a heap. Because, every insertion takes O(logn) time and hence n elements would take O(nlogn) time

But in many places it is written that the creation of a heap can be optimized to O(n) time i.e. a linear time?But it is not clearly explained how?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optimal method doesn't need logn time for inserting a node.

> The optimal method starts by arbitrarily putting the elements on a
>   binary tree, respecting the shape property (as the tree could be
>   represented by an array). Then starting from the lowest level and
>   moving upwards, shift the root of each subtree downward as in the
>   deletion algorithm until the heap property is restored. More
>   specifically if all the subtrees starting at some height `h` (measured
>   from the bottom) have already been "heapified", the trees at height
>   `h+1` can be heapified by sending their root down along the path of
>   maximum valued children when building a `max-heap`, or minimum valued
>   children when building a `min-heap`. This process takes `O(h)` swap
>   operations per node. In this method most of the heapification takes
>   place in the lower levels. Since the height of the heap is `logn` ,
>   the number of nodes at height  is `h`. Therefore, the cost of
>   heapifying all subtrees is:
>
> <sub>h=0</sub>∑<sup>logn</sup> n/2<sup>h+1</sup> = O(n *
>   <sub>h=0</sub>∑<sup>logn</sup>h/2<sup>h</sup> )   which is less than
>
> O(n * <sub>h=0</sub>∑<sup>∞</sup>h/2<sup>h</sup> )
>
> ```
> since h / 2h converges to 2 as it is an infinite series
> ```
>
> it is equal to `O(n)`

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap

Comment: You might want to attribute your source material: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap